# Word read from document INTO a string array in C

Tags: c

I am trying to read contents of a text document, word by word and then copy it into an array of strings. First i open the file then using fscanf with while i read word to 'x'. This x is then assigned to the array assuming max word length to be 50. Inside i print both x and array value. Both prints correct values. But later if i print the contents of array outside the while every thing goes wrong. All the array words have the same value. That is the last read value from the file.
First I tried it with linked list but got same result. But this also gives same result. Outside the logic block all array values or node values have the last read word.
Please help me with this...

```
 int i=0,wCnt=0,j;
        int N=600;
        char **word_array = (char **) calloc(N,sizeof(char*));
        if(f = fopen("input.txt","r"))
        {
            /* assumes no word exceeds length of 150 */
            while (fscanf(f, " %149s", x) == 1) 
            {
                if(wCnt==N){
                    N = N+400;
                    realloc(word_array,N);
                }
                //printf("x=%s\t",x);
                word_array[i] = (char *) calloc(50,sizeof(char));
                word_array[i] = x;
                printf("x=%s arr=%s\t",x,word_array[i]); // Gives correct output                    
                wCnt++;
                i++;
            } 

            // Here the code goes goes wrong. The last word gets print 137 times(wCnt)
            for(j=0;j<wCnt;j++)
            {
               printf("%d->%s\n",j,word_array[j]);
            }
        }
```

The output i am getting is:

```
0->growing
1->growing
2->growing
3->growing
..
```

when 'growing' is the last word in the document. But when I print value of 'X' inside while loop, i got correct output which looks like:

x=In        x=recent        x=years x=there x=has   x=been  x=a     x=growing

Comment: [`realloc(word_array,N)`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/memory/realloc) Um. that call *returns* something you may be interested in.

Comment: `word_array[i] = x;` copies a **pointer**. You may need to copy the contents (allocate space and use `strcpy()` probably).

Comment: @pmg I was still reeling from the blind invoke of `realloc`, i didn't even notice the ensuing memory leak and improper assignment.

Comment: strcpy() also gives the same output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code has multiple issues, including:

- Disregarding the return value of `realloc()`
- Assuming a fixed 50-char buffer can hold a string that may be 150 chars wide (terminator included).
- Disregarding the memory allocation (leaking it) for each word and simply saving the address of `x` as the pointer for the current word.
- Not closing your file.

The third of these would exhibit itself by (a) leaking memory, and (b) all entries in your word table would have the *same address* (of the local x buffer)

I'm pretty sure you looking for something like this, which addresses each of the items above.

```
FILE *f = NULL;
int i=0,j;
int N=600, M=400;
char x[150];

// allocate initial table of pointers, all set to null.
char **word_array = calloc(N,sizeof(*word_array));
if (word_array == NULL)
{
    perror("Failed to allocate pointer array");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}

if((f = fopen("input.txt","r")))
{
    /* assumes no word exceeds length of 150 */
    while (fscanf(f, " %149s", x) == 1)
    {
        if(i == N)
        {
            // attempt resize of table, result stored in a temporary
            //  a NULL return means resizing couldn't happen and we're
            // not left with much we can do about it.
            void *tmp = realloc(word_array, (N+M) * sizeof(*word_array));
            if (tmp == NULL)
            {
                perror("Failed to expand pointer array");
                exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
            }

            // resize worked. make sure the expansion area contains
            //  NULL pointers, as we haven't set them yet. then update
            //  the new size limit.
            word_array = tmp;
            memset(word_array+N, 0, M*sizeof(*word_array));
            N += M;
        }

        // compute length *once*
        size_t wlen = strlen(x);

        // use computed length to allocate a dynamic buffer large
        // enough to hold the incoming data. again, check for 
        // failure before proceeding.
        word_array[i] = malloc((wlen+1) * sizeof(char));
        if (word_array[i] == NULL)
        {
            perror("Failed to duplicate string");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }

        // allocation succeeded. We don't need strcpy
        //  since we already know how much data to copy
        //  over (wlen+1, the +1 for the terminating null char)
        memcpy(word_array[i], x, wlen+1);

        // output string from pointer array to prove that worked
        printf("%d ==> %s\n", i, word_array[i]);

        // adjust to next slot to populate in the pointer array
        ++i;
    }

    // finished with file.
    fclose(f);
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! It works perfectly... But i didn't understand the problem with that code. Could you please explain it...?

Comment: @aswathip the bullet list at the top of this answer is designed to explain *precisely* that. I've annotated the source with-comments that will hopefully help explain better why this code works, and where your's fails by association.

Answer (score 2):

I don't see declaration of 'x', but assume that it is char*. On the line

```
    word_array[i] = x;
```

you are not copying the string to the table, but only setting the first char* to point to x. The solution would be to use strcpy or similar, maybe like this:

```
    strcpy(word_array[i], x);
```

Comment: 'x' is char*. strcpy() also gives the same output.